# How to make use of service port when doing DNS resolution

Tags: docker, dns, registration, consul

I have [consul](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/) and [registrator](http://gliderlabs.github.io/registrator/latest/) running. I can start services in docker containers:

```
docker run -d -P --name=redis redis
```

And `registrator` is, as expected, able to register the services in `consul`:

```
http http://localhost:8500/v1/catalog/service/redis

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 308
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 04 May 2018 11:33:50 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Consul-Effective-Consistency: leader
X-Consul-Index: 34
X-Consul-Knownleader: true
X-Consul-Lastcontact: 0

[
    {
        "Address": "127.0.0.1", 
        "CreateIndex": 34, 
        "Datacenter": "dc1", 
        "ID": "48b6c821-3b93-dbf4-394e-5024123ea7df", 
        "ModifyIndex": 34, 
        "Node": "863e97e527c3", 
        "NodeMeta": {
            "consul-network-segment": ""
        }, 
        "ServiceAddress": "", 
        "ServiceEnableTagOverride": false, 
        "ServiceID": "polyphemus.wavilon.net:redis:6379", 
        "ServiceMeta": {}, 
        "ServiceName": "redis", 
        "ServicePort": 32769, 
        "ServiceTags": [], 
        "TaggedAddresses": {
            "lan": "127.0.0.1", 
            "wan": "127.0.0.1"
        }
    }
]
```

I can then use `consul` DNS services:

```
» dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 redis.service.consul

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 redis.service.consul
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62382
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;redis.service.consul.          IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
redis.service.consul.   0       IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#8600(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri May 04 13:31:21 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 65
```

This is all fine. This basically means that I can start using consul to locate my services, so that something like this:

```
curl -X GET http://myservice.service.consul
```

Would work from inside my container. But ... there is one piece missing here: `registrator` is aware of the IP **and** the port where the service is running. I can check this via a special dns `SRV` request:

```
» dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 redis.service.consul SRV

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 redis.service.consul SRV
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52758
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;redis.service.consul.          IN      SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
redis.service.consul.   0       IN      SRV     1 1 32769 863e97e527c3.node.dc1.consul.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
863e97e527c3.node.dc1.consul. 0 IN      A       127.0.0.1
863e97e527c3.node.dc1.consul. 0 IN      TXT     "consul-network-segment="

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#8600(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri May 04 13:36:02 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 149
```

My question is: how do I integrate this in my application? Let's say I am writing a `python` application using `requests`. How would DNS resolution locate and use the port that is being exposed by the service?

To be clear: the information is properly registered in `consul`, how do I use this information from the application?

I see different options:

- implement a "consul DNS resolution" layer in my application (as a library), which makes `SRV` DNS (or API) requests to consul in order to locate IP and port.
- force the containers to always expose port `80` (I am doing http REST services), so that DNS resolution does not need to care about the port.

The first option implies some refactoring of the application, which I would like to avoid. The second option implies that I need to fiddle with all services configuration.

Is there a better alternative? Is there a transparent way of integrating `SRV` DNS requests when doing name resolution, and automatically making use of the port instead of using port `80` (or `443`)?

I do not see how this would be feasible at all with `python` `requests`, or with `curl`, or with any other tool: we always need to manually specify the port when using those libraries / tools.

And a related question: when / how are `SRV` DNS requests used? It seems those provide exactly the information that I need, but normal DNS resolution does not make use of it: clients are always making assumptions about the port where the service is running (`80` for `http`, `443` for `https` and so on) instead of asking the DNS server, which has the information.

Answer (score 1):

Few ways in which we handled this problem:

- Use a docker overlay network for container to container communication. In this case, your ports can be static (at the container level) and you can assume the port number while making connections
- Use "consul-template" to generate a config file with IP and port info read from consul. This consul-template command will typically run as your docker entry point and will in turn launch your actual app. Whenever there is a change in consul, consul-template will regenerate the file and can be configured to reload/restart your app

Thanks,
Arul

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative within the constraints of DNS or using the Consul API directly, as you've already alluded to above; as it says [here](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/load-balancing-strategies-for-consul#Cons):

> ...In this mode, applications and services talk directly to Consul each time they want to find other services in the datacenter....[Cons] Requires using the HTTP API directly in the application OR making DNS
>   queries and assuming port OR making two DNS queries to find the
>   address and port

That same link however, does offer up some alternatives, which always involve an intermediary. In the case of *Fabio*, effectively straight DNS is used, with association from the app to the port through a consul service tag, rather than any direct reference from the application to a [service] port.